# How can I edit WebViewPage (from metadata)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My model has only a `{get;}` method and not a `{set;}`.
I'm trying to fix that, and it takes me to my model on the WebViewPage (from metadata) page.

But when I try to type in any keys on that page - nothing happens. There's a little icon that says that the page is locked.

Where can I find that page, and how can I unlock it?
And is there any other way to create a setter, besides for making a new model?

Comment: Show some code please.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is: **how to open Model file for edit?**

I believe you have your View file open and are hitting **F12** on the `Model`, this would take you to `WebViewPage<TModel>` class.

This is incorrect, `TModel` is a generic type and you should not (and cannot) edit `WebViewPage<TModel>`.

On top of your view, would must have something like:

```
@model Student
```

Here, `Student` is your actual model type (I am using Student as an example). So you need to open the file which has the definition for `Student`.

Comment: Yes, I have that. But then when I try to loop through my model with a foreach loop, I get an error saying: `Test.Models.Student WebViewPage<Test.Models.Student>.Models {get;} foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'student' because 'student' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: The error that you are talking about has absolutely nothing to do with the question. If you want to add setter to your model, you need to modify the model file (not `WebViewPage<TModel>`). If you want to iterate through your model, the it has to implement `IEnumerator` (or in simple words, you can only iterate through a list of students not a single student).

Comment: Thank you. But it is a list. 
I have this in my controller - `var ListOfStudents = _context.Students.ToList();
            return View(ListOfStudents);` 
And in my view I'm using my model as an IEnumerable -  `@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Students>`
So then what can be the issue by trying to loop through that list?

Comment: now you are asking a totally different question. It should go into a new question

Comment: Thank you. You helped me to specify my problem and now it works.

Comment: Glad it works, it's better to mark the answer as "accepted" if it has helped you to solve the problem instead of leaving a comment.